# ReactJS - Showing some elements and a button to show more

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm using React, with the Flux architecture.

In a certain part of my app, I need to show some elements (let's say, 6) and, if there's more, a button that will display the rest of them when clicked.
As I'm using Flux, I want my components to be as stateless as possible. So far I've tried:

```
let elements = [...] //Array with elements, passed as a prop to MyApp
class MyApp extends React.Component {
...
  render(){
    var elements = this.props.elements.map((elem, i) => {
      if (i == 5)
        return <More />
      if (i > 5)
        return;
      return (
       <ShowElement key={i} />
      )

  return <div>{elements}</div>
  }
}
```

I think I could make this work by passing the remaining elements to my `More` component as prop, but it feels wrong. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as showing 6 items and rest when button is clicked, this is way to do it using state:

```
let elements = [...] //Array with elements, passed as a prop to MyApp

class MyApp extends React.Component {

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      all: false
    };
  },

  render(){
    return <div>{this._renderElements(this.props.elements, this.state.all)}</div>
  },

  _renderElements(elements, showAll) {

      const _elementsToRender = [];
      const _elements = elements.splice(0); // clone array
      let remainder = [];

      if (!showAll) {
        remainder = _elements.splice(6);
      }

      _elements.forEach(el => {
          _elementsToRender.push(
              <ShowElement {..el} />
          );
      });

      if (remainder.length > 0) {
          _elementsToRender.push(
                <button onClick={evt => this.setState({ all: true })}>show all</button>
          );
      }

      return (
          <div>
            {_elementsToRender}
          </div>
      );
  }
}
```

And if you want to keep your component stateless you could pass something like showAll prop and make `<button>` (or whatever custom element you use) trigger action that will change showAll value in store and emit new value so component updates that way.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your more elements in a span or div with a style={moreSty}. The default for moreSty is display: 'none'. The click method for the more button will set the moreSty to display: 'inline' or 'block'.